# Why doesn't Nuxtjs update template when data changes?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs, vue-reactivity

I have a component in Nuxt with the following HTML in the template:

```
<div class="slider" id="slider" ref="slider" :style="'transform: transitionX(-' + sliderPosition + '%)'">
```

Then I also have a data variable:

```
export default {
      data() {
         return { 
            sliderPosition: 0
         }
      },
      methods: {
         moveLeft() {
            this.sliderPosition -= 25
            console.log(this.sliderPosition)
         },
```

Now, every time I click the button that triggers the method, the console logs out the incremented sliderPosition value.
But in the template it always stays 0 and never updates - the transitionX is never changed (shows 0% in Chrome inspector and doesn't change).

Why could this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no `transform` function `transitionX` - [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function). I guess you wanted `translateX`
2. Your `sliderPosition` is negative and you have a `-` in the style expression. So if the value of `sliderPosition` is `-25` the style is `translateX(--25)` which is not valid

So just to be clear, this is not a problem of Vue not updating the DOM but instead problem of browser not accepting invalid style...

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      sliderPosition: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    move(percent) {
      this.sliderPosition += percent
      console.log(this.sliderPosition)
    },
  },
  computed: {
    sliderStyle() {
      return {
        transform: `translateX(${this.sliderPosition}%)`
      }    
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.14/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="move(-5)">Move left</button>
  <button @click="move(5)">Move right</button>
  <div class="slider" id="slider" ref="slider" :style="sliderStyle">This is OK!
  </div>
  <div class="slider" id="slider" ref="slider" :style="`transform: translateX(-${this.sliderPosition}%)`">This is not!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is hard to comprehend the fact I typed transition instead of translate :) But I was so focused on the 0, that I did not even pay attention to that and the double minus. Thank you!